# What does 'of the sort' mean in meaning and grammar?

Tags: meaning, appositives

From Jim Miller. (2002). An Introduction to English Syntax. p.109.

> Nouns in English do not fall into different grammatical classes **of the
> sort** found in Latin.

As the book has discussed in Chapter 5 on the lexicon, the english noun classes fall into : concrete vs abstract,common vs proper,and so on. But, Latin has gender and declinations classes.

So, 'Nouns in English do not fall into different grammatical classes found in Latin.' also makes sense.

"the sort" here seems to be redundant, and in my view it functions as an appositive.

Likewise, in *The city of Newcastle lies at the mouth of Newcastle river.*,if we have already known the city is Newcastle, we could also remove Newcastle.

So, does 'the sort' really function as what I think?

Comment: Why do you think "the sort" might be an appositive? What phrase do you think it is in apposition with?

Comment: @gotube I have re-edited it.

Comment: Using "of the sort" makes it more general or vague than without - "different grammatical classes found in Latin" would mean specifically the 5 classes of nouns declined as in Latin; with "of the sort" it means anything similar with e.g. 3 or 6 classes of nouns. [Check the dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/of%20the%20sort), particularly the examples.

Comment: @Stuart F So,can 'of the sort'  be moved to the end? That is,*Nouns in English do not fall into different grammatical classes found in Latin of the sort .*

Comment: @mrwang: *He needed a small basket of apples of the sort used in pies.*  "of the sort used in pies" modifies "apples".  He needed the type of apples that are used in pies. sort  = variety, type, ilk, kind.  If you omit "of the sort" the sentence still makes sense, but "of the sort" makes clearer that a specific kind of apple is desired: apples for *baking*, as "apples for eating" like Red Delicious or Fuji are not usually used in pies. In your example, it's better to say that English nouns don't fall into classes *like those* found in Latin (of the sort), not into Latin classes *directly*.

Comment: "Of the sort [**that are**] found in Latin."

Comment: @Mr.Wang So you think "the sort" is in apposition with "classes"?

Comment: @gotube 'the sort' is in apposition with 'different grammatical classes'. As far as the comments above are concerned, it seems to be  an apposition, but also not to be.

Comment: @TimR Apples can be a type of apples that are used in pies. But,grammatical classes can not be a type of classes that are found in Latin.  We could say words can be a type of words found in Latin,not grammatical classes. I  am not sure whether you could understand what I'm trying to say.

Comment: @Mr.Wang The phrase "of the sort..." directly modifies "classes. If it were in apposition, it would have to be a noun phrase as well, and it would have to refer to *the same thing* as "*different grammatical classes*", not further define it. So no, it's not an appositive.

Comment: There is no apposition here at all with "different grammatical classes".  "of the sort found in Latin" is a prepositional phrase that modifies "grammatical classes" and the prepositional phrase contains a relative clause modifying "sort".

Comment: @mrwang: I must not understand what you're trying to say.  "a type of apple**s**"  (plural) is ungrammatical.  And on a semantic level, you seem to be conflating *category* and *member of category*. It's like saying "dogs are a kind of dogs [sic]" or "celestial bodies are a kind of celestial bodies", neither of which makes sense to me.

Comment: @TimR Sorry, my grammar needs improvement. But I see what you mean.The author uses 'of the sort' to convey a sense of similarity rather than accurate equality.

Comment: @Mr.Wang  Yes, "of the sort found in Latin" could be paraphrased as "like those found in Latin". And instead of "accurate equality" you could use the word "identical".

Comment: @TimR Thank you very much for your patient and detailed answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a prepositional phrase, but the object of the preposition "of" includes the relative clause "found in Latin"

"Sort" means "type",  and "the sort found in Latin" means "the type of noun classes that are found in Latin"  (and I know that the noun classes found in Latin are the gender and declinations classes)

You can't remove "of the sort" because the relative phrase "found in Latin" is part of the phrase.  You could remove the entire prepositional phrase "of the sort found in Latin".

Comment: So a paraphrase would be “The type of different grammatical classes found in Latin do not apply for nouns in English.”

Comment: But you *can* remove "of the sort". In this *exact* context, that's not very idiomatic unless we add some kind of "determiner" before the preceding "head noun" that the relative phrase "found in Latin" modifies: *...do not fall into **the / those** different grammatical classes found in Latin.* Or we could replace "of the sort" with just *...do not fall into different grammatical classes **as** found in Latin.* Both those alternatives sound fine to me (though I'd say they convey *slightly* different nuances).

Comment: "of the sort" is not a complete phrase in the example given, since the relative clause is bracketed within it.  You may be able to rephrase this without the words "of the sort" but that is sort of different. Just removing "of the sort"  would make the relative clause apply to the noun "classes" and not "sort" and would have a different structure.

Comment: The author uses 'of the sort' to convey a sense of similarity rather than accurate equality.